# C File Transfer between a Windows computer and a Mac/Linux computer?

Tags: c, file, tcp, p2p, transfer

If I have a Windows computer and a Mac computer or a Linux computer, is there a recommended library way to transfer a file between them that doesn't involve FTP, passwords, etc.

For example:

Computer #1:  Windows 7 with a local ip of 192.168.1.5
Computer #2:  Mac Lion with a local ip of 192.168.1.9

Is there a known peer-to-peer file transfer library out there for C and/or C++ or is this a common method for this using an established library or something I'm not aware of.

Comment: Plain TCP sockets or anything you can build on top of them yourself. Our company has several products that might help you (MsgConnect, SecureBlackbox). I recommend looking at MsgConnect, as it's a peer-to-peer communication library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the library [libcurl.](http://curl.haxx.se/)

There is no login and password prompts. just give the login and the password in the curl config with the function `curl_easy_setopt` and all the work will done by the libcurl

Comment: In a way that does not involve FTP?

Comment: there is no lgin and password prompts. just give the login and the password in the curl config with the function `curl_easy_setopt` and all the work will done by the libcurl

Comment: My question states "in a way that does not involve FTP or passwords".  I'm looking to facilitate the transfer of files if needed by a multiplatform application amongst computers connected to the same router.

Comment: OK I did not get your question. libcurl support other protocols other than the FTP you could check them in the website of libcurl

Comment: I'm looking for something easier than writing sockets code and reinventing the wheel.  Unless I have to.